# How to parse webpage for S&P500 P/E ratio

Tags: html, r

I am trying to import the current P/E ratio for S&P 500 from this webpage:
http://www.multpl.com
Where, below the chart,it says "current:", providing the current value (today the value is 24.11).

Is there a way to parse this webpage to automate importing it into R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only PE ration you can use this

```
library(XML)
library(stringr)
url<-htmlParse("http://www.multpl.com/")
PE<-xpathSApply(url,"//div[@id='current']",xmlValue)
str<-str_replace_all(PE," ","")
str<-str_replace_all(str,"\n","")
begin<-str_locate(str,":")[[1]]
end<-str_locate(str,"\\+")[[1]]
PE_ratio<-as.numeric(str_sub(str,begin+1,end-1))
PE_ratio
```

Comment: Fantastic, yes that's exactly what I was looking for.